# Insert into (тип memory) вешает базу на высокой нагрузке

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Столкнулся с проблемой на проекте. Сайт с 30 тыс в сутки, вдруг стал посещаемый с 1,5 млн в сутки.
Работаю на PHP+Mysql. Есть админ сервера, я в это не бум бум. Арендую выделенный сервер. сам проект написан мною с нуля. Начинали с ним с малыми посещениями и все было ок. С такими цифрами сталкиваемся впервые, и у админа опята мало в этом. поэтому есть определенные затыки.
Вводные: MariaDB . у всех таблиц тип InnoDB

Сама суть проблемы:

Считаю кол-во просмотров articles как INSERT INTO stat_articles (id, id_article, ip) и раз в минуту эти данные обрабатываю по крону и очищаю таблицу.  Была проблема, когда был сильный наплыв юзеров, и тип был InnoDB. Поставил тип Memory и все было хорошо, пока сегодня не столкнулся с очередным пиковым одномоментным большим наплывом юзеров и phpmyadmin увидел такую картину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И таких строк было более 200. Что-то мне подсказывает, что должно быть какое-то решение в настройках самой БД.

Вот собственно и вопрос. Что подкрутить, чтобы все заработало как часы? Или может какое то решение подскажите?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-delayed/

Comment: Правда ли что ошибки возникают в момент обработки таблицы кроном?

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, правильно я понял, что в случае использования INSERT DELAYED вместо INSERT запросы будут в памяти ждать свой очереди и пропускать все другие запросы к этой таблице, пока не освободится выполнение? Есть ли какие то минусы использования этого delayed (первый раз о нем от вас услышал) в данном случае?

Comment: по поводу "в момент выполнения крона" - я к сожалению не смог (не успел, не подумал) отследить этот момент.  возможно. но идею я понял, попробую delayed + всю ночь думал как таблицы статистики оптимизировать

Comment: Больше CPU нужно для отложенной записи.

Comment: так вот с этим проблемы. CPU на 90-100% мощности в это время работал и база зависала. Уже присматриваю помощнее, но нужно время на переезд

Comment: CPU надо профиливать чтобы понять кто его использует. Может у вас веб сервер всё CPU извёл, а базе данных ничего не осталось. Тогда вообще надо в другом месте чинить. Слишком много вопросов.

Comment: нет. там mysql грузит все. Я что мог уже оптимизировал. Но сервер не справляется именно в моменты,  когда очень сильный одновременный наплыв юзеров на страницы с новостями, вижу кучу этих INSERT однотипных и с разными id_article (можно было бы подумать на ддос, но не похоже, судя по запросам).

Comment: Ищу варианты пока не переедем на новый сервера, что можно сделать в случае повтора ситуации

Comment: может какие то параметры в кофиге mysql нужно посмотреть? мой админ не знает куда копать, не было опыта с таким

Comment: СООТВСТВЕЕНО, если INSERT DELAYED требует больше CPU, делаю вывод, что этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: "Waiting for table level lock" как бы намекает что вся таблица заблокирована до тех пор как предыдущая операция не закончится. Лично мое мнение: перевел обратно на InnoDB (так как может работать в режиме row lock) и посмотрел бы в сторону индексов/Isolation Levels. Для справки: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/mysql-memory-table-getting-many-locks/10821#10821

Comment: Спасибо, Arkee. Есть над чем задуматься!